# SUM and IF operator with SQL

Tags: sql, if-statement, sum

I have a column in a table with values of 1 given to users who purchase a trial, and 0 given to users who do not. 
I want the total of users who have purchased the trial. The unique identifier in the table is given by user_id.

Will the IF operator work? Can anyone explain why or why not?

Comment: You do not require an `if` in this case. Simple `where` clause will work

Answer (score 4):

You would just do:

```
select count(*) from users where trial=1
```

or

```
select sum(trial) from users
```

Why are you thinking to use IF?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the query:
`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE TRIAL=1`

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just specify the condition in `COUNT()` function itself like

```
select count(case trial when 1 then 1 else null end) from users
```

Using a `SUM()` function like

```
select sum(case when trial = 1 then 1 else 0 end) from users
```